# woocommerce additional fees based on product input

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

The products contain 2 different Attributes (packaging= crate/container) and I have to put 3 different fee and name for 2 different attributes . The fee also need Multiply Fee by Quantity and display name & fee 1 by 1 on cart page and checkout page. In addition, the fee on cart page and checkout page will auto calculate to the total price . Any plugin or add the code for this problem?  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 0.01;
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

Here is a sample code on how to add fee